# How to disable iframe from javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a button that opens a Paypal iframe for payment purpose. But I want to disable this iframe from my js script. I've tried to target the parent element of that iframe, and add an event listener that stops propagation on click, but this doesn't work. Is there any way to prevent that iframe from opening?

Comment: "_I have a button that opens a Paypal iframe_" Don't open the iframe then ..? You can't access a third-party document, hence there's not much you can do with the opened iframe in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can change src prop and hide this element like this:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId");

iframe.src = "";
iframe.hidden = true;
```

Also you can use this:

```
iframe.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: That's what I'll probably do, but I wanted to show an alert or a popup when the user would click on the iframe, instead of opening the iframe

Comment: @GherghelAndrei, frame.onclick = () => { alert("click") }